# Is it possible to decrypt data on-chain so that others do not see it

Tags: evm, signature, encryption, smart-contract

I was wondering if it was possible to do secure encryption/decryption or signature and verification entirely on-chain?

To my understanding, this is impossible because in order to sign a message we need the private key, but we cannot store this on the blockchain for security reasons. Similarly, for decryption, the private key used for decryption and the decrypted message would be available for everyone to see on the blockchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if it was possible to do secure encryption/decryption or signature and verification entirely on-chain?

Everything on-chain is public, so decryption without leaking private data is not possible.

There are several examples you can check a signature on-chain using Solidity smart contract programming language using `ecrecover()` function.